# Using an abstract Base Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a set of controllers that should only be accessible if you are an admin (as opposed to a regular user).

Thus, in the constructor for each of the controllers, I would do:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if (! is_admin()) {
         show_404();
    }
}
```

Instead of adding this code to the constructor of every Admin Controller, is there a better way to do this?

I was thinking I could create a Base controller called `Admin_Controller` that would look like this:

```
public class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
         //the above code goes here
    }
}
```

And then all my other controllers can extend this class, instead of the `CI_Controller` class. The only problem with this is, I need to include this file at the top of my other controllers, or CodeIgniter cannot find `Admin_Controller`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want to have multiple base classes try this article from Phil Sturgeon: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY Cheers, Bart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

place this in your application/core folder:  MY_Controller.php *(note the correct use of capitals)*

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct() 
{
     parent::__construct();
     if (! is_admin())
     {
          show_404();
     }
}
```

Then in all your normal controllers that you want users to be logged in

```
class Whatever extends MY_Controller
{
   public function __construct() 
    {
         parent::__construct();
    } 
}
```

[See userguide here on extending core classes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: Thanks. This works. However, how could I have multiple different base classes for this? For example, the above class checks `is_admin()`. Suppose I wanted another class to extend which checks `is_member()` ?

Comment: I'm also searching for something very similar. I have a bunch of options controllers that have a lot of similar actions and I would like to DRY some code up into an abstract controller. However, the method in this answer only allows for one abstract controller...not many.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could use [Hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)
I've done the same thing, but I require a much more precise control so I have to check on every controller. Not all controllers are forbidden for single users.